# Clear other apps data programmatically?

Tags: java, android, rooted-device

I am developing an android application and i need clear the data of another application upon clicking an button.

i.e.: if i click button name "gmail" in my app,the data should be cleared of that "gmail" app

doubt:

1.Is it possible?
2.Do we need to be rooted our android device in order to do this?
  ° because greenify works with root access to force stop the other app flexibly.

I know that greenify works without root but pop that "force stop" ui screen of each single app to do that action.

MY APP FUNCTIONALITY:
I just wanted to develop an android apllication named "anti-theft cloud apps"
simply if an thief stols our mobile then my app detects when he changes the sim or an unique code send by mobile owner through sms from other mobile and logouts all the cloud based applications like gmail,google photos etc to protect our data to be stolen ,so in order to do that i thought of clearing other apps data(like gmail) PROGTAMITICALLY to logout. Is it possible

Comment: Looks like evil thing, definitely Android won't allow that. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @PradeepSimha i am developing an application "anti-theft" that if a thief stols our mobile then he changes the sim or we send an unique code that will be identified by my app automatically logout's all cloud based applications like gmail,google drive etc will be logout to secure our data from thief,thats why i feel that logout can be done by clearing the app data

Comment: any more answer please

Comment: Your intention may be good, but by default Android doesn't allow to do that for security reasons until and unless phone is rooted.

Comment: Application of this feature can be cleaning of memory - many apps only save to storage and do not clean. Example is Soundcloud app.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with stock Android. You can do it with superuser, access `root/data/data/PACKAGE` and clear its content. But as seen in comment, this seems like evil thing.